# iOS13 Beta / iOS13 requirements TLS Certificate

Tags: security, mdm, ios

this post is about this link [iOS 13 requirements TLS Server Certificate](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176) and two questions that bother me currently.

First of, can anyone tell me, if a SHA2 signature is required **only for my server certificate and it's issuing CA cert** or does **every certificate in the chain of trust** need to be signed with SHA2?

My Situation: *Trusted Root CA cert (SHA1) -> Intermediate CA cert (SHA256) -> my.domain.com cert (SHA256)*

And my second question is, if anyone has already installed the iOS 13 Beta and could tell me, if there were **changes in the trusted root certificates** until now? 
 I especially want to know, if the *GlobalSign Root CA R1-SHA1* was removed. I don't think so, becaus it'll be valid until somwhere around 2028 but I don't want to build something up on my believes, if I can have facts.

If you have any insight on that, I'd really appreciate your input here.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot confirm but the article you a referring to states very clearly its only for Server and Issuing Certificates.
In other words SHA-1 Root certificates are not impacted.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. Currently it seems that you are right. I just forgot about the post here.